# PHP glob() returns an empty array

Tags: php, glob

I have this code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if( isset( $_SESSION[ 'user' ] ) )
    {
        $pictures = glob( "http://localhost/wandelverhalen/cms/newPictures/*.*" );
        echo count( $pictures );
        echo "\n";
        echo( $_SESSION[ 'user' ] );
     }else{
        echo('You are not logged on.');
     }
?>
```

I have 50 files in the directory http://localhost/wandelverhalen/cms/newPictures. But the code echoes:
0
Johannes

This is the javascript that calls the php-code:

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( response ){
        var data = response;
        console.log( data );
    },
    error: function( err ){
        console.log( err.responseText );
    }
});
```

I found various answers to similar questions, but none of them solve my problem.

Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the absolute path to glob function

```
__DIR__."/wandelverhalen/cms/newPictures/*.*"
```

Use for all type images

```
glob(__DIR__."/wandelverhalen/cms/newPictures/*.{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Rakesh. But I get the same result. __DIR__ is the directory that contains the php-script. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wandelverhalen\styles\functions\php). This results in: glob( C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wandelverhalen\styles\functions\phpwandelverhalen/cms/newPictures/*.*) which is a non existing dir.

Comment: @johannes make sure your path should `wandelverhalen/cms/newPictures`

Comment: Thank you. The path was the problem indeed. I found this: glob( "../../../cms/newPictures/*.{jpg,JPG,JPEG,gif,png}", GLOB_BRACE );